# Topology and Differential Games

Tags: general-topology, optimization, game-theory

I'm a engineer who is making research on differential games in multiagent control. I was reading a tutorial on differential games and the author advised to get the required math background from the book "Optima and Equilibria" for Aubin. In Aubin's book, it assumes good knowledge of topology which was the first time to hear that expression.
I started to read in some topology books, but i actually found most of them confused.

Can you please suggest a good book that is much more intuitive with good examples rather than pure math ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the book from James R. Munkres "Topology a First Course" published by Prentice-Hall (1975). Even though the book seems quite out-dated, it, nevertheless, introduces the reader in Topology with very nice and intuitive examples. Especially, it covers the main topics, which are of importance to understand differential games. I would strongly recommend you to study this book first before you go in Aubin's book. However, I think that this book is not the best to start with differential games. A nice book and more appropriated is "Dynamic Noncooperative Game Theory" by Tamer Basar and Greet Jan Olsder published by Academic Press (1995). Also a very nice book is "Differential Games in Economics and Management Science" by Engelbert Dockner, Steffen Jorgensen, Ngo Van Long, and Gerhard Sorger published by Cambridge University Press (2000).